# HRESULT E_FAIL return when call CreateFileAsync in KnowFolders

Tags: windows-store-apps

I've face with a very strange problem, I create a simple application which only create file in the KnowFolders:

```
var name = Path.GetRandomFileName();
var file = await KnowFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I've already add permission for the Music folder, but the HRESULT E_FAIL still return when Create file, this happen on some PC, I search many on internet but still cannot see the root cause or solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a miserable error.  Do avoid creating randomly named files in a directory that's visible to the user.  GetRandomFileName() cannot ensure that the file is unique.

Comment: I cannot create file or folder even name is simple.